# Javascript not working in Edge/Firefox and Safari but on Chrome it works

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I had a JavaScript snippet on my WordPress site that were used to make the "menu filter element" work, I already inserted it about three months ago and everything worked.

Until today I realized that the menu no longer works when I click on the buttons it does not change the filters as if there were no code presented there. I switched between browsers to troubleshoot the issue, but seems it only works on Chrome, not all other browsers.

Here's the snippet:

```js
filterSelection("all")

function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

// Show filtered elements
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

// Hide elements that are not selected
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current control button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

The code was adapted from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_portfolio_filter.asp.

Comment: What debugging have you tried? E.g. console logging each step of those functions. And are you sure that your Chrome isn’t picking up an older, working version. Also, how are you linking this code into WP?

Comment: Look at the devtools console log on your browsers. Javascript Code that doesn't work often shows errors in the log, with line numbers. Please [edit] your question to show us the output if you still need help. And, w3schools? Really? Friends don't let friends...

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual HTML it is difficult to assess the total functionality of your code. However, the functions you are using (w3AddClass and w3RemiveClass) can be simplified. Here is a re-write of `w3AddClass()`:

```
const w3AddClass=(element,name)=>
  element.classList.add(name);
```

and `w3RemoveClass()`:

```
const w3RemoveClass=(element,name)=>
  element.classList.remove(name);
```

`filterselection(c)` can be rewritten as

```
const filterselection(c)={
 document.querySelectorAll("filterDiv").forEach(d=>(c=="all"||d.classList.contains(c))&&d.classList.add("show"));
}
```

As I am writing this on my smartphone I was not able yet to test the above. But I am confident they will work.